# Type guard on generic object property doesn't work in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typeguards

As example, I've got a very simple function that sets "true" (boolean) to some named object property:

```
function setTrue<T, K extends keyof T>(host: T, property: K) {
    if (typeof host[property] === 'boolean')
        host[property] = true; // <-- TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
}
```

Can't figure out what's wrong? It seems that type guard `typeof host[property] === 'boolean'` doesn't work in this case. Who knows how to achieve **correct static type check** in this example?

The only workaround I found is if `T extends any` but in this case no type guards are required at all:

```
function setTrue<T extends any, K extends keyof T>(host: T, property: K) {
    host[property] = true; // <-- Always Ok
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there are multiple things contributing to this situation.

One issue is that the compiler does not do type guard narrowing when the property key being tested is a variable; see [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) for more information.

Another factor is that a read and subsequent write of a property whose key type is not known to be a singleton cannot be done safely.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693).  The compiler doesn't realize that `property` is the same exact key in the two lines.  All it understands is that the properties being accessed have the same *type*, which is not strict enough unless the types are already known to be a singleton.

Finally, the compiler just isn't very good at control flow analysis in the face of values that depend on unspecified generic type parameters like `T` and `K`.  Even if you test `property` for being a particular subtype of `keyof T`, the compiler will not narrow the `K` parameter, see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) or [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  At best it will narrow the type of `property` to some intersection `K & ...` which may or may not be helpful.

---

One caveat to present here before showing workarounds: this isn't technically safe.  If your host has a property whose type is known to be the boolean literal `false`, as in:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: false
}
declare const foo: Foo;
```

Then you will run into problems:

```
setTrue(foo, "bar");
foo.bar; // false or true?
```

Your implementation of `setTrue()` just checks to see if `foo.bar` is of `boolean` type, which it is.  But now we've lied to the compiler by setting a property of *type* `false` to the value `true`.  So `foo.bar` is now `true` at runtime but `false` in your IDE.

I'm going to ignore this wrinkle, but it's still there, so be careful.

---

So, workarounds.  The easiest by far is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and move on:

```
function setTrue<T, K extends keyof T>(host: T, property: K) {
  if (typeof host[property] === 'boolean')
    (host as any as Record<K, boolean>)[property] = true; 
}
```

Here we've asserted that if `host[property]` is of type `boolean`, then we will treat `host` as `Record<K, boolean>`: an object with property values of type `boolean` at keys of type `K`.

Less straightforward is to refactor into some smaller pieces that the compiler can either verify by itself or that can be made into a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), to walk the compiler through the type analysis the way we want it to:

```
function setTrueKnownBoolean<K extends PropertyKey>(host: Record<K, boolean>, property: K) {
  host[property] = true;
}

function isBooleanProperty<K extends keyof T, T>(
  host: T, property: K): host is T & Record<K, boolean> {
  return typeof host[property] === "boolean";
}

function setTrue2<K extends keyof T, T>(host: T, property: K) {
  if (isBooleanProperty(host, property)) {
    setTrueKnownBoolean(host, property);
  }
}
```

The function `setTrueKnownBoolean` is only allowed to be called on `host` objects which are known to have `boolean` properties at the `property` key(s), so the implementation needs no type check inside.  The function `isBooleanProperty` acts as a type guard to narrow the type of `host` from `T` to `T & Record<K, boolean>`.  And now `setTrue2()` can be implemented by composing those two other functions.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQCoCcSoDwYA0iA0oqgB5SpgAmyiA1qgJ5zCIYB8AFABZxkUAFydiAByxxxqLFBaiSASkQBvALAAoRIhgce8me0QChAbUnTZ8gLqIAvI8QByAEZw4AG1QBDMM6UtHR1+QShEHwY-FgiGACVUCDgsWjwSYncvXzAuJQspGTkWO3tEKBxUAG4tAF8tLRgwaixgHwhURAAxDzUgxFcfLFFWzzRarVpEz0GOpLAhRGAPUW64as00TAqeJbhiACIBrH2ldd2AOiPKxAB6G8WfUY7ksoqAfnrNUEhYBBR0bC4EhgOAAdzAACEPN4-GlyFQaPREAAFArWFgkVi8UwiRAJJIpNIZaHZLgSNFFRQqDTaExhfJWIolV64dZ1TRab7QeBIGDIKFZPyoxnyOGUah0BjMNgcIicXh9HGiOWWQryKmiHG6BgYRAAMjxiWSqXS-RJfi4vVpWHQICwSEMqGMOIZauKDich3NYH2bM+XN+SE2gNQACYxQjJUxWMY5dxQkJleSRQpSNS+npEDw+QKYWBhW6E1Bk26lOnaTpgxVgWDId6iyX0ac+uyakA)